Installing x3270 for Hercules on WSL
getting these errors during sudo apt install x3270:
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 3270-common amd64 4.1ga10-1.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 x3270 amd64 4.1ga10-1.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 xfonts-x3270-misc all 4.1ga10-1.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ibm-3270/3270-common_4.1ga10-1.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ibm-3270/x3270_4.1ga10-1.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ibm-3270/xfonts-x3270-misc_4.1ga10-1.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap

I have tried pointing to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com but can't find the right combo to use
in /etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/resolv.conf looks like this since nameserver 10.255.255.254 doesn't work either
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search attlocal.net


Nothing anyone here can help you with. Right now your DNS is not working correctly. Try again later. The error is very clear in your question Temporary failure resolving

update: I removed archive.ubuntu.com from the sources and used only us.archive.ubuntu.com - the result was worse

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package x3270

this problem has been going on for 3weeks

I will try noble numbat next
